# How to remove addEventListener after calling it each time

Tags: javascript, onclick, addeventlistener, event-bubbling

I have two types of dropdowns, I want to select item from selected dropdown, and append it on list. After clicking dropdown button first time and select item from it, each next clicks return duplicate appends on list.

```js
    document.querySelector('.selected-items').addEventListener('click', e => {
      const overlay = document.querySelector('.hidden-overlays-select')
      const button = e.target.classList.contains('select-option')

      rect = e.target.parentElement.getBoundingClientRect()
      row = e.target.parentElement;

      addItem(row);

      overlay.style.display = 'inline-block'
      overlay.style.top = Math.round(rect.top) + 'px';
      overlay.style.left = Math.round(rect.left) + 'px';

    });

    addItem = (row) => {
      document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-list .list').forEach(list =>
        list.addEventListener('click', e => {
          let option = e.target.classList.contains('list');
          option = e.target.textContent;
          if (option) {
            const li = `
              <li class="select-option" style="margin-right: 1rem;">
                ${option}
              </li>`;
            row.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", li)
          }

          document.querySelector('.hidden-overlays-select').style.display = 'none'
        }));
    }
```

```css
li {
    cursor: pointer;
    list-style: none;
  }

  .hidden-overlays-select {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    margin-top: .5rem;
  }
```

```html
<div class="hidden-overlays-select">
    <ul class="dropdown-list">
      <li class="list">Test One</li>
      <li class="list">Test Two</li>
      <li class="list">Test Three</li>
      <li class="list">Test Four</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="dropdown-list">
      <li class="list">Test One</li>
      <li class="list">Test Two</li>
      <li class="list">Test Three</li>
      <li class="list">Test Four</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="selected-items d-flex align-items-center flex-fill">
    <ul style="display: flex;">
      <li class="select-option" style="margin-right: 1rem;">
        Click Me
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Here is the sample codes, I did googling both google and stack overflow, but no luck with the same issue

Comment: you use [removeEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener) read the docs carefully to see how to use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just have a reference to each element in your list by using the class (Example: **dropdown-list**) Here's a working solution:

```js
   document.querySelector('.selected-items').addEventListener('click', e => {
  
      const overlay = document.querySelector('.hidden-overlays-select')
      const button = e.target.classList.contains('select-option')

      rect = e.target.parentElement.getBoundingClientRect()
      row = e.target.parentElement;

      overlay.style.display = 'inline-block'
      overlay.style.top = Math.round(rect.top) + 'px';
      overlay.style.left = Math.round(rect.left) + 'px';

    });


    const el = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-list');
    el.forEach(function(item, index){
          item.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            var option = e.target.textContent;
            if (option) {
              const li = `
                <li class="select-option" style="margin-right: 1rem;">
                  ${option}
                </li>`;
              row.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", li);
            }
            document.querySelector('.hidden-overlays-select').style.display = 'none';
        });
    });
```

```css
li {
    cursor: pointer;
    list-style: none;
  }

  .hidden-overlays-select {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    margin-top: .5rem;
  }
```

```html
<div class="hidden-overlays-select">
    <ul class="dropdown-list">
      <li class="list">Test One</li>
      <li class="list">Test Two</li>
      <li class="list">Test Three</li>
      <li class="list">Test Four</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="dropdown-list">
      <li class="list">element 1</li>
      <li class="list">element 2</li>
      <li class="list">element 3</li>
      <li class="list">element 4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="selected-items d-flex align-items-center flex-fill">
    <ul style="display: flex;">
      <li class="select-option" style="margin-right: 1rem;">
        Click Me
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: I have dropdown with the same classes

Comment: @Abdushukur I updated my answer to use the same class for both lists :). Please take a look at it again. If it helps you please mark this answer as the correct one. Thanks